# Really strange render behavior in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, render

I was playing a little bit with JavaScript and jQuery and I noticed something wrong in Google Chrome but not in Mozilla Firefox. The problem is that **ALL** the inputs update correctly except the one with the **Opacity** label.

It gets updated in a strange way like when I focus in or focus out or when I click five or six times.

Here's the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w9S7Y/49/). (use the arrows in each input to change value)

Why Google Chrome renders the `Bad Input` number field like that and the other fields not?

If you don't get any strange behavior it seems it's from my machine (Linux Mint 17), but don't now for sure.

**EDIT:**

I'm expecting the inputs to increment/decrement instantly when you click the arrows.For some inputs works and for others the update is delayed or something.

Comment: I am not familiar with the syntax you are using.  The problem may be here `Opacity: <number></number>`.  Try `Opacity: <input type="number" id="opacity" />`

Comment: You're not being very specific. "In a strange way"? "like that"? "strange behavior"? Please describe exactly what you expect to happen and exactly what's happening instead.

Comment: I said "when I loose focus". the JS behind is not too important.the thing is the the inputs update in different ways.check fiddles

Comment: It may be very clear to you in the fiddles -- because you already know what **IT** is. For the rest of us, you may want to describe that behavior fully in your question. As @Blazemonger clearly asked, what do expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: It would help us a lot if you'd reduce that fiddle to the minimum code needed to recreate your problem.

Comment: I just did that now. pay attention to the 'Bad input' . increase it 10 -20 times and see how it updates(not instant).

Comment: Reproduced, using Mac OS Mavericks and the latest Chrome / Firefox.

Comment: Can you make a really short fiddle with the following : only one input and your two buttons (up / down), the minimum css, the minium javascript. It's really difficult to see what is the problem with all the unnecessary code

Comment: (O.o)Strange! Try shuffling the browser in the fiddle example.

Comment: If I comment out /*-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px black);*/ from the .colorPicker rule, it works OK for me in Chrome.

Comment: @sifriday You just saved my day. +10. Why it does like that with the filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reproduced, using Mac OS Mavericks and the latest Chrome / Firefox.

For some reason it breaks with the -webkit-filter rule in the .colorPicker styles. You can replace it with a box-shadow, and it works OK, and looks the same:

```
.panel, color .colorPicker {
...
  /*-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px black);*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w9S7Y/52/

...but exactly **why** remains a mystery! As Vivek points out in the comments above, in the fiddle in the orig post, you can also force the inout to redraw by resizing the window. So for some reason the Blink repaint process is getting blocked by the -webkit-filter.

Currently reading through Blink bugs...

Comment: Where did you know it breaks there? You use some css validation tools or something?

Comment: instinct, I guess. Your code looks nice and works fine in Firefox, so I felt you were right that it was strange behaviour rather than something programmatic. So I zoomed in on 'strange' things and started disabling them to see what happens!

Comment: Thank you so much for you spent time.You really made my day! Have a nice day too! Cheers!!!